# master-detail with Windows Phone 7 listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've got a very basic and common scenario I'm trying to work through in my WP7 silverlight application.

I have a basic listbox inside a panorama control that I'm databinding a collection of objects to.  Right now i have a datatemplate that just renders a single textbox for every row.

I would like to implement some sort of master/detail strategy for this.

For example, my listbox is just a list of people

```
John
Bob
Bill
Mike
...
```

If I were to click on John, I want to pass an ID for that row into some type of subview that will show a simple form that would let me edit the details of that row (invoking some transition, of course)

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Phone Databound Application project template can be used as a model for how to build this.

During the CTP the equivelant project template had a transition animation, but this one doesn't.

However you can implement the transition following either Christian Schormann's CL02 Mix 10 talk or Shawn Wildermuth's blog post.

[Shawn Wildermuth - Bring Back Page Transitions to the Windows Phone List Application Template](http://wildermuth.com/2010/07/16/Bring_Back_Page_Transitions_to_the_Windows_Phone_List_Application_Template)

Comment: thanks for the pointer.  for future purposes, in short its just a matter of setting the OnSelectionChanged event on the listbox to use the navigation service to take you to another xaml page.  pretty straightforward